# iOS Swift - SharkORM won't commit

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using SharkORM on iOS Swift project and I'm having problem with a specific object. I have other objects in the project that works, but this one.

My class is like this:

```
import Foundation
import SharkORM

class Exam: SRKObject {

    dynamic var serverId: NSNumber?
    dynamic var type: String?
    dynamic var when: String?
    dynamic var file: String?
    dynamic var filename: String?
    dynamic var url: String?

    func toJson() -> [String:Any?] {
        return [
            "name" : type,
            "date" : when,
            "serverId" : serverId,
            "file" : file,
            "filename" : filename,
            "url" : url,
            "id" : id
        ]
    }

    static func fromJson(_ json: [String:Any?]) -> Exam {
        let exam = Exam()
        exam.id = json["id"] as? NSNumber ?? NSNumber(value: 0)
        exam.type = json["name"] as? String ?? ""
        exam.file = json["file"] as? String ?? ""
        exam.filename = json["filename"] as? String ?? ""
        exam.url = json["url"] as? String ?? ""
        exam.serverId = json["serverId"] as? NSNumber ?? NSNumber(value: 0)
        exam.when = json["date"] as? String ?? ""
        return exam
    }

}
```

I add to an array objects that needs to be saved and after user press save button, the app starts committing it.

```
    // save exams
    for exam in self.examsToSave {
        if !exam.commit() {
            print("Error commiting exam.")
        }
    }
    if let rs = Exam.query().fetch() {
        print("exams: \(rs.count)")
    }
```

The commit method returns true and I added a print right after it finishes committing and result is zero.

Any idea?

Comment: `when` it is **keyword**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem right after post it. In my text here, my variable "when" was colored like a keyword. I just changed the name to "whenDate" and it started committing. Weird it didn't show up any error or a crash. Anyway, a variable named "when" is not allowed inside a SRKObject.

Answer (score 1):

Given same Commit problem, figured best to keep to topic here. And I've spent number of hours trying to debug this so thought I'd try this:

I have a simple class (and overly simplified but tested as provided here):

```
class user: SRKObject {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
}
```

(No, no odd syntax coloring on the object property names.)

And I do the following (simplified test case), first defining

```
public var currUser = user()
```

Then in a function:

```
let users = user.query().fetch() as! [user]
if users.count > 0 {
    currUser = users[0]
    NSLog("Num users \(users.count) name \(currUser.name)")
} else {
    self.currUser.name = "T1 User"
    if !self.currUser.commit() {
        print ("Failed to commit")
    }
    else {
        let u = user.query().fetch()
        print("Num users \(u.count)")
    }
}
```

The commit() call succeeds -- at least I don't get the "Failed to commit" message. However, I do get zero count in the last fetch().

Viewing the DB file (in Simulator) from a "DB Browser for SQLite" shows the DB is created fine but the "user" record is not in there, and neither is the "committed" data.

BTW when I had this code in SRKTransaction.transaction, it DID fall into the failure (rollback) block, so yes, did get a transaction error, but tracking that down will be next.

In the meantime, appreciate in advance any help given this case as presented should work.

Comment: I added a new answer related to your problem.

Comment: I see that, and I need to build some status so my +1 doesn't show up.

Comment: Sorry for making a mess of this thread... I need to build some status so my +1 doesn't show up. Thanx. Interesting. Is the class member variable definition incorrect? Do you know something that made you try with local variable? I do need to use 'user' elsewhere though.... My example is contrived: there are permissions on the user, etc. I assume I can return the local var from the function?

Comment: I didn't test, but I think if you declare your class member like this "public var currUser: user?" and then instantiate it locally, it will also work. I don't know why the class member instantiated directly won't work. I did some research and didn't find anything about it. Maybe, try to open a ticket at SharkORM Github (https://github.com/sharksync/sharkorm). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

@retd111, I copied and pasted your code and got the same error.

Then, I moved the `currUser` to a local var, like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var currUser: user? = nil

    let users = user.query().fetch() as! [user]
    if users.count > 0 {
        currUser = users[0]
        NSLog("Num users \(users.count) name \(currUser!.name)")
    } else {
        currUser = user()
        currUser!.name = "T1 User"
        if !currUser!.commit() {
            print ("Failed to commit")
        }
        else {
            let u = user.query().fetch()
            print("Num users \(u?.count ?? 0)")
        }
    }

}
```

It works without problems.

For some reason, if you instantiate the currUser as a class member variable, as your example:

```
public var currUser = user()
```

it won't work.